# java.nio Selectors and SocketChannel for continues Streaming

Tags: java, nio

I am currently using the java.nio.channel.Selectors & SocketChannels for a application that will open 1-to-many connections for continues Streaming to a Server. I have three threads for my application: StreamWriteWorker - performs write operation to the SocketChannel, StreamReadWorker - reads bytes from the buffer and parse content, and StreamTaskDispatcher - performs Selector's selection for readyOps and dispatches new runnables for the worker threads.

Problem - Invocation on the Selector's selection method only returns a value > 0 (valid readyOps) on the first invocation; I am able to perform a write and send data on all ready channels that one time, but all of the following invocation of the Selector's selection method returns 0.

Question: Do I need to invoke close on the SocketChannel after every Read/Write (I hope not!)? If not what could be the cause for the SocketChannels not being available of for any Read/Write Ops?

I am sorry I cannot post the code, but I hope I have explained the problem clearly enough for someone to help. I have searched for answers and I see you cannot reuse a SocketChannel connection after it close, but my channel should not be close, the server never receives EOF stream result.

I made some progress and figured out that the write operation was not occurring on the server app due to json parsing error. So now my SocketChannel on the client app code becomes ready for another write operation after it process a read operation. I guess this is the TCP nature of SocketChannels. However, the SocketChannel does not become available for another read operation on the server app side,. Is this normal behavior for SocketChannels? Do I need to close the connection on the client side after the read operation and establish a new connection?

Here is a code sample of what I am trying to do:

```
package org.stream.socket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;

public class ClientServerTest {

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]> dataQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>();
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    private HashMap<String, Integer> uuidToSize = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    private class StreamWriteTask implements Runnable {
        private ByteBuffer buffer;
        private SelectionKey key;
        private Selector selector;

        private StreamWriteTask(ByteBuffer buffer, SelectionKey key, Selector selector) {
            this.buffer = buffer;
            this.key = key;
            this.selector = selector;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            byte[] data = (byte[]) key.attachment();
            buffer.clear();
            buffer.put(data);
            buffer.flip();
            int results = 0;
            while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                try {
                    results = sc.write(buffer);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (results == 0) {
                    buffer.compact();
                    buffer.flip();
                    data = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                    buffer.get(data);
                    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                    key.attach(data);
                    selector.wakeup();
                    return;
                }
            }

            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            key.attach(null);
            selector.wakeup();
        }

    }

    private class StreamReadTask implements Runnable {
        private ByteBuffer buffer;
        private SelectionKey key;
        private Selector selector;

        private StreamReadTask(ByteBuffer buffer, SelectionKey key, Selector selector) {
            this.buffer = buffer;
            this.key = key;
            this.selector = selector;
        }

        private boolean checkUUID(byte[] data) {
            return uuidToSize.containsKey(new String(data));
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            buffer.clear();
            byte[] data = (byte[]) key.attachment();
            if (data != null) {
                buffer.put(data);
            }
            int count = 0;
            int readAttempts = 0;
            try {
                while ((count = sc.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    readAttempts++;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (count == 0) {
                buffer.flip();
                data = new byte[buffer.limit()];
                buffer.get(data);
                if (checkUUID(data)) {
                    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                    key.attach(data);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Clinet Read - uuid ~~~~ " + new String(data));
                    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                    key.attach(null);
                }
            }

            if (count == -1) {
                try {
                    sc.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            selector.wakeup();
        }

    }

    private class ClientWorker implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Selector selector = Selector.open();
                SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open();
                sc.configureBlocking(false);
                sc.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9001));
                sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(65535);

                while (selector.isOpen()) {
                    int count = selector.select(10);

                    if (count == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        final SelectionKey key = it.next();
                        it.remove();
                        if (!key.isValid()) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (key.isConnectable()) {
                            sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                            if (!sc.finishConnect()) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                        }

                        if (key.isReadable()) {
                            key.interestOps(0);
                            executor.execute(new StreamReadTask(buffer, key, selector));
                        }
                        if (key.isWritable()) {
                            key.interestOps(0);
                            if(key.attachment() == null){
                                key.attach(dataQueue.take());
                            }
                            executor.execute(new StreamWriteTask(buffer, key, selector));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Handle Exception
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){

            }

        }
    }

    private class ServerWorker implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Selector selector = Selector.open();
                ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
                ServerSocket socket = ssc.socket();
                socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9001));
                ssc.configureBlocking(false);
                ssc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(65535);
                DataHandler handler = new DataHandler();

                while (selector.isOpen()) {
                    int count = selector.select(10);

                    if (count == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        final SelectionKey key = it.next();
                        it.remove();
                        if (!key.isValid()) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                            ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
                            SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
                            sc.configureBlocking(false);
                            sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                        }
                        if (key.isReadable()) {
                            handler.readSocket(buffer, key);
                        }
                        if (key.isWritable()) {
                            handler.writeToSocket(buffer, key);
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private class DataHandler {

        private JsonObject parseData(StringBuilder builder) {
            if (!builder.toString().endsWith("}")) {
                return null;
            }

            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) parser.parse(builder.toString());
            return obj;
        }

        private void readSocket(ByteBuffer buffer, SelectionKey key)
                throws IOException {
            SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            buffer.clear();
            int count = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int readAttempts = 0;
            try {
                while ((count = sc.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    readAttempts++;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (count == 0) {
                buffer.flip();
                StringBuilder builder = key.attachment() instanceof StringBuilder ? (StringBuilder) key
                        .attachment() : new StringBuilder();
                Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
                CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
                decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
                System.out.println(buffer);
                CharBuffer charBuffer = decoder.decode(buffer);
                String content = charBuffer.toString();
                charBuffer = null;
                builder.append(content);    
                System.out.println(content);
                JsonObject obj = parseData(builder);
                if (obj == null) {
                    key.attach(builder);
                    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("data ~~~~~~~ " + builder.toString());
                    JsonPrimitive uuid = obj.get("uuid").getAsJsonPrimitive();
                    key.attach(uuid.toString().getBytes());
                    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                }
            }

            if (count == -1) {
                key.attach(null);
                sc.close();
            }
        }

        private void writeToSocket(ByteBuffer buffer, SelectionKey key)
                throws IOException {
            SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            byte[] data = (byte[]) key.attachment();
            buffer.clear();
            buffer.put(data);
            buffer.flip();
            int writeAttempts = 0;
            while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                int results = sc.write(buffer);
                writeAttempts++;
                System.out.println("Write Attempt #" + writeAttempts);
                if (results == 0) {
                    buffer.compact();
                    buffer.flip();
                    data = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                    buffer.get(data);
                    key.attach(data);
                    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                    break;
                }
            }

            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            key.attach(null);
        }
    }

    public ClientServerTest() {
        for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
            JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
            String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            uuidToSize.put(uuid, uuid.length());
            obj.addProperty("uuid", uuid);
            String data = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10000);
            obj.addProperty("event", data);
            dataQueue.add(obj.toString().getBytes());
        }

        Thread serverWorker = new Thread(new ServerWorker());
        serverWorker.start();

        Thread clientWorker = new Thread(new ClientWorker());
        clientWorker.start();

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientServerTest test = new ClientServerTest();
        for(;;){

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need these three threads? You certainly don't need the writing thread, and with a bit of restructure along the lines intended by NIO you can get rid of the reading thread as well. Multithreading and NIO really don't mix. If you want multithreading, use java.net and blocking I/O.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I started off with the three threads because timeliness is a important factor; I did not want to have a Read waiting on Write or vice versa, and I will be work with a large amount of data. Do you have a response in regards to the problem I stated?

Comment: I'm not sure the problem you stated that motivates the three threads even exists. You are in *non-blocking mode.* Nothing will wait, except the select() call. But if your select() returns zero, nothing is ready. Closing channels at random won't change that.

Comment: I made some progress and figured out that the  write operation was not occurring on the server app due to json parsing error. So now my SocketChannel on the client app code becomes ready for another write operation after it process a read operation. I guess this is the TCP nature of SocketChannels. However, the SocketChannel does not become available for a read operation on the server app side. Is this normal behavior for SocketChannels? Do I need to close the connection on the client side after the read operation and establish a new connection?

Comment: A channel becomes ready for writing when there is room in its output buffer. You are *told* about it by a selector if and only if you are registered for OP_WRITE at the time. I still don't understand your last question. I suggest it is some you posted some code.

Comment: I will write some sample code to post

Comment: I have added the code it is a very simplified version of what I am try to do in my application at work, but hopefully this help; for some reason the ServerWorker.class blocks forever on the selection statement in the sample.

Comment: I will suggest one last time that you do all this in one thread. The complications you are introducing by changing the interestOps to exchange control with your threads are clearly breaking things. Make it work in one thread and then see if you genuinely have a threading problem at all. I don't believe you do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The correct way to process `OP_CONNECT` is to attempt `finishConnect()` once, and if it succeeds deregister `OP_CONNECT` and register `OP_READ` or `OP_WRITE`, probably the latter as you are a client. Looping and sleeping in non-blocking mode doesn't make sense. If `finishConnect()` returns false, `OP_CONNECT` will fire again.
2. Your processing of `!key.isAcceptable()`, `!key.isReadable()`, and `!key.isWriteable()` makes absolutely zero sense whatsoever. If the key is acceptable, call `accept()`. If it's readable, call `read()`. If it's writeable, call `write()`. It's as simple as that.
3. You need to be aware that channels are almost always writeable, except for the brief periods when their socket send buffer is full. So only register for `OP_WRITE` when you have something to write, or better still *after* you've tried a write and got a zero return; then when `OP_WRITE` fires, retry the write and deregister `OP_WRITE` unless you got another zero.
4. You are being far too economical with your `ByteBuffer`. In practice you need *one per channel.* You can save it as the key attachment so you can get it back when you need it. Otherwise you don't have any way of accumulating partial reads, which are certain to happen, or any way of retrying writes either.

Comment: Okay so I do not think the OP_CONNECT is a big deal, but I change it; in my code at work I usually initialize my connections before, but I will try it your way and see if it helps. As far as your second bullet that was obviously a typo, I was putting sample together late. In regards to our third bullet, this is intriguing to me because my OP_WRITE fires initially, but does not fire until after a OP_READ has been fire that is subsequent to it. I am also writing out the full contents of the byte[] and it is not surpassing the limit of my buffer.

Comment: Lastly, I am not sure if I follow you on me not being able to handle a partial read or write, my code is handling that case.

Comment: After I got to work everything you said started to make sense. My code is working the way it is suppose to work. Thanks for your patience and  help. I will post a new question in regard to performance and memory management, I look forward to your wisdom.

Comment: @RobertBrooks In your new code you are ignoring the result of `write()`. That doesn't conform with my point (3) above. THe number of write attempts is immaterial: if you encounter a zero-length write, your socket send buffer is full and the only thing to do is return to the select loop and wait for an OP_WRITE.

Comment: So basically it is a waste of time to recursively called the write method because the SocketChannel underlying buffer is full? How can that happen if there is only one SocketChannel? Is this due to the fact that the server could have filled the socket send Buffer right before the client's DataHandler object try to handle a write to the SocketChannel

Comment: @RobertBrooks I would call that iteration, not recursion ;-) The socket send buffer fills when the receiver's socket receive buffer fills, which happens when you are writing faster than he is reading.

Comment: Okay, but let's just say the client write to the socket channel, and before the server does a read, it performs a write to the socket channel, and performs a read from the socket channel; will the server read the data that it wrote, along with the data that the client wrote? For your scenario above I   synchronized the client's OP_WRITE, so that all the SocketChannel will only become interested OP_WRITE after it has processed a read, of course excluding the initial write operation.

Comment: this means the client waits for the server to process all data from the socket channel and send a ACK.

Comment: @RobertBrooks I don't understand. The server will read what the client wrote; the client will read what the server wrote. I've already described he OP_WRITE becomes not ready, and it has nothing to do with server processing. It has to do with server *reading*. The ACK sent by the TCP stack doesn't wait for server reading or processing.

Comment: Okay I made the changes at work to handle partial writes and reads. However, my application is at a stand still state because the client has wrote enough data to the SocketChannel to fill the server's socket receive buffer, but the server's selector never triggers for a read operation on the selection call; I also had to add a 100ms interrupt to my selection call because it blocks indefinitely sometimes. I will try to put together some sample code.

Comment: @RobertBrooks OK. You should really always use a select timeout, but 100ms is pretty drastic. You need to be aware that SelectionKey.interestOps() will block if called from another thread while the selector is concurrently selecting. You need to do selector.wakeup() first. Ditto register().

Comment: I have posted the new code. I did not add the selector.wakeup(), but I will try it at work tomorrow.

Comment: @Robert See my point (1) above, which you still haven't implemented correctly. I don't know why you're setting the interestOps to zero; and I still don't see any need for the executor in the client. NIO is non-blocking: you can do it all in one thread.

Comment: Okay good catches... I made the change per your point above... As far as the executor, I will need this solution to scale up to use multiple socket channels and based on my reading, to off load the read/write task to a thread pool is the way to go; right now being that I only have the thread pool at one (for simplicity) it makes no sense. Lastly, setting the key.interestOp to zero will avoid a race condition because the ClientWorker thread will keep going to the next selection invocation and the read/write thread maybe still processing; however, this is only necessary for the ClientWorker.

Comment: I have posted the code for a single thread server and multi-thread client. Everything seems to work. However my code at work is similar, but I am getting a Broken Pipe exception. I am going to try to duplicate the problem and create a new question