# FileChannel.transferTo() keeps transferring 0 bytes?

Tags: java, nio

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11305386/668963) yesterday, and I was convinced that a single-threaded file server will fit my need. Yes, with a single thread, the file server works pretty well(for only small files), it can handle about 300 requests per second, now the problem is that the **write**(I use `FileChannel.transferTo()`) part of the server will block for quite a while for serving large files, which keeps other connections from being connected.

I noticed that `FileChannel.transferTo()` sometimes transfers **0 bytes** when transferring large files(around 800KB).  It fails with: `java.io.IOException: Try again.`  This was on Android.

Because I put `FileChannel.transferTo()` in a loop, I can get the situation where `FileChannel.transferTo()` runs thousands of times to ultimately transfer the entire file.

My question is what causes `FileChannel.transferTo()` fail to transfer the bytes requested? How do I tackle this problem and make my file server more responsively for handling large files?

Comment: are you facing any IOException?

Comment: `java.io.IOException: Try again.` I tested on Android.

Comment: Duplicate of [Java NIO SocketChannel.read() with multithread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305386/java-nio-socketchannel-read-with-multithread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method can't possibly return zero and throw an exception at the same time, but I suggest that when you get 'try again' you should reduce the transfer count. I would keep halving it until the condition goes away. You have to call `transferTo()` in a loop anyway, so it doesn't really affect your code too much.

Comment: You are right, 'zero' and 'try again' are not possible to occur at the same time, but they both happened. I have read the answer and the comments you posted for [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716057/java-nio-selectors-and-socketchannel-for-continues-streaming), that helps me understand some tricky parts of NIO. I will try to adapt my understanding to the implementation of the file server. I will need worker threads to handle `read`s and `write`s.

Comment: @Neveek No you won't, you only need to do what I said above.

Comment: indeed, I tried using multiple worker threads to perform IO, and it didn't show better performance, it is even slower than single thread. Why? could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Neevek I'm having too much trouble following this topic over the *N* threads you have started. There is no reason to expect a multithreaded file transfer to perform significantly faster than a single-threaded transfer. The network isn't multithreaded, and neither is the disk.